Transit in Germany with type D visa from Italy for non-EU citizen
I am a non-EU citizen in Italy, and I have a multiple-entry type-D student visa, valid for 1 year (expires on 8th October).
I still don't have a valid residence permit, but I need to travel back to my country, the flight transit in Germany for a couple of hours, and the same route for my flight back (returning on 30th September)
I have been asking around to understand if I will face problems with the transit since I don't have a residence permit yet, But I got contradicting info, according to the university office, the visa allows me to travel for the first three months in the Schengen area, but I didn't see any rule about that.
I am from Syria, if that makes any difference.

Just for completeness, have you applied for a residence permit in Italy? Having the documents that prove you have applied is not necessary, but it will make for a more convincing story if you are questioned.

I was in a similar situation for transit through Frankfurt with a D Visa prior to receiving my permesso di soggiorno. The outgoing journey (from Italy to destination) had no problem. On the return to Italy via Frankfurt there was a little more discussion. I was asked to show Carta d'Identità as well as the receipts for the Permesso di Soggiorno. It also took about 15-20 minutes and two immigration officers. If you have connecting flight, maybe make sure to add a buffer if you can.

Also, make sure you take some digital copies of your receipts and maybe even a hardcopy as well. My approach was always to be armed with a surplus of documentation, which was frustrating. Maybe invest in a binder for documentation so you can easily find / handover documentation.

As a Syrian national you are required to hold, at minimum, a transit visa. You have a D visa as you're residing in Italy for study. You have a recipe also for residency, so you're doubly-fine.

@fdcpp that sounds like a good answer.

How did this work out in the end?

@fdcpp
I got lucky and received the resident permit 3 days before the flight.
So now I don't know whether to accept an answer or leave it as it is.
